# Coordinate Transformation in Classical Mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

The coordinates in one inertial frame are represented by $(x,t)$. Under coordinate transformation, the coordinates in another inertial frame can be represented by $f(x(t),t)$. It can be shown that the acceleration $a'$ in the later frame can be expressed as:
\begin{equation}
a' = \frac{d^2x'}{dt'^2}=a\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} + v^2\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}} + 2v\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}\partial{t}} + \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{t^2}},
\end{equation}
where $v$ and $a$ are the velocity and acceleration respectively in the first frame mentioned. 
As both are inertial frames, we would expect 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} = 1
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}  
\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}} = \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}\partial{t}} = \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{t^2}} = 0.
\end{equation}

From those we can get $f(x(t),t) = x + Ct + D$ after integration. How can I interpret this $f(x(t),t)$?

Comment: as a [galilean transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation)?

Answer (score 1):

> From those we can get $f(x(t),t) = x + Ct + D\,$ after integration. How can I interpret this $f(x(t),t)$?

The constants of integration $D$ and $C$ are, respectively, the displacement between the origins of the two frames at time $t=0$ and the constant velocity with which the origin of the primed frame moves with respect to the origin of the unprimed frame.

In short, this is the galilean transform, in the sense of an affine galilean transformation. (It's your integration constant $D$ that is of concern here. It's not needed, and getting rid of that results in the standard galilean transform.)

Side note: You have implicitly assumed that time marches to the same beat in both frames, as does the galilean transform.